# Html tag effect in PDF report

Tags: html, pdf, tinymce, report

I have a text field in my report. The value for the text field is taken from DB. The value stored in the DB has tinyMCE effect. I have to show with the same effect while displaying in the PDF report.

Let me know if there is any solution available or any work around for this.

*Eg:*
Data in DB:

```
<p><strong>Example<strong> <em>sdfsdfddf</em> <u>zxcvcvcx xcvxc</u></p>
```

Right now I am getting the exact text string where as I need them to be parsed while filling the report.

Comment: can't you take on of the many tools out there to convert thml code to pdf?

Comment: i just want to fetch data from database and write it in the pdf format